# access variable within same class which keeps changing

Tags: java, swing

The program structure is given below. The requirement is that I need a variable  inside  class_name() which gets generated inside  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e). The option of making the variable as class variable wouldn't solve the problem as the variable keeps changing depending on the mouse click event. What could be the possible solution ?

```
public class class_name extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  class_name()
    {
     //variable needed here
    }
    public class xyz extends MouseAdapter
    {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
         {
         //variable generated here
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: and why is this impossible if you use it as a class member?

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to *achieve* - I don't understand your description at the moment. Is it the *value* which needs to keep changing, or something else?

Comment: Please respect the Java naming conventions. There's no way that a value initialized in a mouse event listener is available in the constructor of the frame. If the frame is being constructed, how could a mouse event have been fired?